# Power Automate - Embed 2 images within an email

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, image, email-notification

I was able to successfully embed an image into a Power Automate email utilizing "Get File Content", "Compose" (with this expression base64(body('Get_file_content'))), then I reference it in the email with `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@{outputs('Compose_2')}"width="75%" height "200">`.

This works perfectly, but I'd like to add a 2nd image to this email.  Basically, this first image sits on the top of the email as a Header.  I have a 2nd image in the same Image Library in SharePoint that I'd like to place as a Footer.

The problem is if I follow the same procedure, I end up with the same image on the bottom (obviously).  But how can I reference a 2nd output?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must be using output from same "Compose" action in both the places, you should use outputs from second "Compose" action in the image at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using "Outputs" from same "Compose" action in both the places

Follow below steps to for 2nd image:

1. Add one more "Get File Content" action with the URL path of 2nd image and "Compose" action to get the Base64 image content from this 2nd "Get File Content" action.
2. In the 2nd `img` tag (in footer) use "Outputs" from the 2nd compose action used in above step from "Dynamic content" - Make sure you are not using "Outputs" from first compose action.
3. It is confusing to choose correct outputs as all the "Outputs" from compose action will have similar names in "Dynamic Content" pane:

   [image]
4. So, I will suggest you to rename Compose actions to avoid confusion:

   [image]
5. Using correct Outputs should work for you:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you!  Yeah I realized that after I added the 2nd Compose, I was still only referencing the first image.  All set now.  I appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Use two Get file content or Get file content using path actions to get the two images. Then use two variables to store their Base64 encoded content.

[image]

Then use the variables when generating the body of the email message.

[image]

Here's the result.

[image]